# Is there a way to change the folding tree appearance?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I thinking whether there's a setting where I can change the folding tree appearance like in Notepad++ with + and - and trailing red line

The best one yet is indent guides. But it disappears when I select other indents in the function.

Comment: Have a look at `Bracket Pair Colorizer` by CoenraadS (there is a v2). The icons can be changed, they where + and - in version 1.36. Search the repo and copy them over to your install

Comment: @rioV8 I have Bracket Pair Colorizer installed. Can you explain how I can access the repo? I have found the installation link to v1.36 but I still have no exact idea how to move forward. I best guess is to install VSC v1.36, find the icon file, paste them in v1.38... seems to be quite a feat. Care to help further?

Comment: clone the git VSC repo. Checkout a commit for version <=1.36 and search for svg files and find the ones with +/- symbols